# Fread blocks eternally on redirected stdout with named pipes

Tags: c, linux

We are trying to communicate between two processes via named pipes that are redirected to stdin and stdout in the child process. The parent process opens the named pipe and calls fdopen on them. The problem we see is that fwrite on this works, however even reading one byte from redirected stdout pipe blocks eternally. 
The code works when using the file descriptors instead of FILE *. What is wrong? Code is a little long, sorry.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int create_fifo()
{
    int file1;
    unlink("fifo-0.0");
    file1 = mkfifo("fifo-0.0",0666); 
    if(file1<0) {
        printf("Unable to create a fifo");
        return 0;
    }
    unlink("fifo-0.1");
    file1 = mkfifo("fifo-0.1",0666); 
    if(file1<0) {
        printf("Unable to create a fifo");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int fd, fd0, fd1;
    pid_t pid;
    char read_buf_p[50],write_buf_p[50];
    char * args[3];
    FILE *fd_stdin_p, *fd_stdout_p;

    create_fifo();
    args[0] = "/bin/cat";
    args[1] = "-n";
    args[2] = NULL;

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {   
        fd = open("fifo-0.0", O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd, 0);
        close(fd);
        fd = open("fifo-0.1", O_WRONLY);
        dup2(fd, 1);
        close(fd);
        execv(args[0],args);
    }
    else
    {
        fd0 = open("fifo-0.0", O_WRONLY);
        fd_stdin_p = fdopen(fd0,"w");
        fd1 = open("fifo-0.1", O_RDONLY);
        fd_stdout_p = fdopen(fd1,"r");
        int sz = fwrite("Hello World", sizeof(char), strlen("Hello World"), fd_stdin_p);
        fread(read_buf_p,1,1,fd_stdout_p);
        printf("%s\n", read_buf_p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of `FILE`-based I/O being "line-buffered", by default. This means that it reads and writes whole lines, and since your data isn't a whole line, it's stuck in the buffer and not passed through to the underlying file descriptor.

Try adding `\n` at the end of the output data, or call `fflush()`.

Comment: As a follow up: another option to do this is the use of setbuf() on a file stream pointer to disable buffering. Depends on what works better for the developer

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of buffering of Standard output.
Just use '\n' at the end of fflush()